# How to get name of all stations in a network in the form of list using obspy?

Tags: python, obspy

I know that get_station method of a client returns an inventory object, but I can't find any attributes or method related to the name of a particular station. Could anyone help me with it? Thank you.

I need to handle data from a series of station in a network, and I don't want to type in the name of every station.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.